# Icon status bar disappearing after launching application mac

Tags: swift, macos, icons, statusbar

I am trying to add a icon to the status bar so I can add a little menu to it with a few actions. But when I am launching the application, the icon shows up for a second orso and then disappears and doesn't return. Below is the code that I use to create the icon:

```
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        let bar = NSStatusBar.system
        let length: CGFloat = -1 //NSVariableStatusItemLength
        var item = bar.statusItem(withLength: length)
        item.button?.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "logo-1"))!
    }
```

How can I fix this so it doesn't disappear again?

Comment: You need an IBOutlet for an NSMenu object + more.

Comment: This tutorial (https://medium.com/@cristi.baluta/status-bar-icon-menu-in-swift-3132f0bef8cf) says that it is possible without creating outlets